# How to get selected textView value(current position) in recyclerview using data binding?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-databinding

I have a `recyclerview` using `databinding`.

I need to get the selected `textview` value from `recyclerview` layout in onClick but I don't know how to get it.

I searched on google and found some solutions but I can't solve my problem.

Can anyone help me?

**Adapter :**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.itemHolder> {
    private StudentAllSessionsAdapter.ClickEvent clickEvent;
    private List<StudentEntry> studentList;
    private RecyclerViewAdapterBinding binding;
    .
    .
    .

    public RecyclerViewAdapter.itemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.recyclerview_student_all_session, parent, false);
        clickEvent = new RecyclerViewAdapter.ClickEvent();
        binding.setClickEvent(clickEvent);
        return new RecyclerViewAdapter.itemHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull RecyclerViewAdapter.itemHolder holder, int position) {
        StudentEntry studentEntry = studentList.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setStudentEntry(studentEntry);
        int scoreSum = database.attendanceDao().getAllScoreStudent(studentEntry.getClassId(), studentEntry.getStudentId());
        holder.itemView.textViewItemRecyclerViewStudentListScore.setText(String.valueOf(scoreSum));
    }

    public class ClickEvent {
        public void onClickScore(int classId, String studentId, String studentName) {
            //I need to get the TextView value of the current position here
        }
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView Layout :**

```
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="clickEvent"
        type="com.example.user.classmanager.RecyclerViewAdapter.ClickEvent" />
    <variable
        name="studentEntry"
        type="com.example.user.classmanager.database.StudentEntry" />
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_item_recyclerView_StudentList"
    style="@style/RecyclerVew_BackGround_all"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_item_recyclerView_StudentList_saveScore"
        style="@style/Button_item_recyclerView_StudentList_saveAbsent"
        android:onClick="@{() -> clickEvent.onClickScore(studentEntry.classId, studentEntry.studentId, studentEntry.studentName)}" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_item_recyclerView_StudentList_score"
        style="@style/TextView_item_recyclerView_StudentList_values" />
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi what value you are setting to textView? I mean in model class which vlaue you set

Comment: @Shahzad Afridi The `textView` value is a sum value so It's not from a model. I just need access to current position `textView` to get value from it.

Comment: I know textView can't be from model. My question was if the field is set to textview from model you can simply get from list with adapterPosition... Incase you want to access textView of clicked position then... continue.

Comment: SetClickListener to root view of item layout then inside onClick listener use findview by id to et textview and ge the value

Comment: @Shahzad Afridi Can you give an example or more explain?

Comment: Please share you complete code of adapter/XML so I can see where you set the value of textView then I will be better to guide you. the above code is not enough give the idea about your question regarding textview.

Comment: @Shahzad Afridi Thank you for take your time for my question. I found a solution to my question. You can see my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way.

**1st :** add a new parameter in onClick button to get text from textView(current position) :

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_item_recyclerView_StudentList_saveScore"
        style="@style/Button_item_recyclerView_StudentList_saveAbsent"
        android:onClick="@{() -> clickEvent.onClickScore(textViewItemRecyclerViewStudentListScore.getText().toString() , studentEntry.studentId, studentEntry.studentName)}" />
```

**note :** The new parameter has a CamelCase name format.

**2nd :** Get the new parameter(textView value) in onClick :

```
    public void onClickScore(String textViewValue, int classId, String studentId, String studentName) {
        //Do whatever you want with textViewValue 
    }
```